# issues using calendar() from momentjs

Tags: javascript, momentjs

Application stores date in ISO format, so August 9, 5:36 PM will be stored as 2017-08-09T17:36:00.000Z.

Assuming today is August 9, 5:36 PM.

However, I am facing issues while displaying this using momentjs's calendar parsing method.

see this:

```
var currentTime = moment("2017-08-09T17:36:00.000Z").calendar() 
console.log('Current Time is ',currentTime);
```

Prints: "Current Time is " "Today at 1:36 PM"

Expected: "Current Time is " "Today at 5:36 PM"

Any idea why it takes back to 4 hours?

Secondly,

The calendar function prints time only for last week date, after that it only shows date.

e.g.
 `var currentTime = moment("2017-08-02T17:36:00.000Z").calendar() 
       console.log('Current Time is ',currentTime);`

Prints: "Current Time is " "08/02/2017"

Expected: "Current Time is " "08/02/2017 5:36 PM".

Comment: I guess it's taking the UTC datestamp you are giving it (the Z on the end) and converting it to local time.  Did you try it without the Z?

Comment: It works if I remove Z at the end, but the issue is that it is how getting stored in database i.e. with Z at the end.

Comment: I found solution for second question: something like this will fix it : `var currentTime = moment("2017-08-02T17:36:00.000").calendar(null,{sameElse: 'MM/DD/YYYY hh:mm'}) `

Comment: Well, the right way would be to make sure the correct datestamps are being stored in the database.  A hacky workaround would be to remove the Z before feeding it into moment, but then your website wouldn't display the right date/times for folks in other time zones.